# Multiset implementation in Ruby

Tags: ruby, set

I am trying to implement the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) definition of a MultiSet and need feedback on the implementation.

```
class MultiSet
  include Enumerable

  attr_reader :members

  def initialize enum={}
    @members = {}
    raise_error unless enum.class.include? Enumerable
    enum.each do |item|
      if @members.include?(item) 
        @members[item] += 1
      else
        @members[item] = 1
      end      
    end  
  end

  def each(&blk)
    @members.each(&blk)
  end

  def == other
    members.to_h == other.to_h 
  end

  def eql? other
    self == other
  end

  def to_h
    members.dup
  end  

  def to_set
    Set.new @members.keys
  end  

  def remove item
    if @members.include?(item) 
      @members[item] = @members[item] - 1
      if @members[item] < 1
        @members.delete(item)
      end
    end      
    self
  end 

  def add item
    if @members.include?(item) 
      @members[item] += 1      
    else
      @members[item] = 1
    end        
    self
  end 

  def empty!   
    @members.clear    
  end 

  def multiplicity item 
    @members[item] == 0 ? nil : @members[item]
  end

  def include? item
    @members.include? item 
  end

  def cardinality
    return 0 if @members.empty?
    @members.values.reduce(:+)
  end 

  def | other
    other.each do |k,v|
      if members.include? k
        members[k] = multiplicity(k) + other.multiplicity(k)
      else
        add k
      end     
    end
    self
  end   

  def & other
    members.each do |k,v|
      if other.include? k
        members[k] = [multiplicity(k), other.multiplicity(k)].min
      else
        remove k
      end     
    end 
    self
  end    

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Sometimes you're skipping parentheses, sometimes you're not. Please be consistent
- Sometimes you're accessing `@members` directly, sometimes you're using the `members` reader method. In some cases that might make sense to do one or the other, but here it's random. Again: Be consistent.
  However, be careful about providing a reader. Right now, I could say `a_multiset.members[some_item] = -100` or something, and things would get weird because I've messed with an internal data structure. A `#members` accessor might be better as simply an alias for `#to_h`
- What is `raise_error`? I don't see it defined anywhere. Which, funnily enough, means that it *does* raise an error - an error telling you that `raise_error` isn't defined.
  If you're going to raise an error, then raise the appropriate one:

  ```
  raise ArgumentError, "enum must include the 'Enumerable' module"
  ```
- `enum.class.include?(Enumerable)` is a roundabout way of writing `enum.kind_of?(Enumerable)`
- Your initializer duplicates logic from you `#add` method; just call `#add` instead.
- `#remove` can be cleaned up a little by postfixing the `if members[item] < 1`, just to get rid of the pyramid indentation.
- Your `#empty!` method should probably be called `#clear`. That's the conventional name used by `Hash`, `Array` and `Set` (as you can tell, since that's what your method calls on the `@members` hash)
- Pretty sure that your `#multiplicity` method is exactly backwards. You're returning `nil` if an item's count is zero. I think you want the exact opposite: Return zero if the item doesn't exist:

  ```
  include?(item) ? members[item] : 0
  ```
- Use your own methods when you can. You have an `#include?` method already, so there's no need to use `@members.include?` all over the place.
- `#cardinality` can be written as just

  ```
  members.values.reduce(0, :+)
  ```

  If you provide an initial value to `#reduce` (the zero), you don't need the extra emptiness-check you have now
- Pretty sure your union method is incorrect too. If a key doesn't exist, you simply add it - meaning it'll have a count of 1. But in fact, it should have the same count as it has in the other set.
  And you can simplify the method, too:

  ```
  def |(other)
    other.each do |key, count|
      members[key] = multiplicity(key) + count
    end
    self
  end
  ```
- Both the union and intersection methods should probably return a new `MultiSet` instance, rather than modify the receiver.

Comment: 1. How would the #members accessor be made alias to to_h,  if I made members private

Comment: @gitarchie I don't know what you're asking there. I'm just saying that a `members` accessor should return a dup of `@members`, like `to_h` does (in other words, it should be an alias) - it should not return the instance variable itself.

Comment: Ok, I fixed all the issues you mentioned and submitted a new version, I realize my union and intersection were wrong so I changed them and leveraging the `add` to actually create the multiset.

Comment: @gitarchie Please don't update your question with new code - but feel free to post a brand new question, if you want! Please see this meta post: ["What you can and cannot do after receiving answers"](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765). I'll take the liberty of rolling back your edit

Comment: @gitarchie I know what you mean about versioning, but questions must stay in lock-step with their answers - otherwise the Q&A format falls apart. However, if you simply include a link to/from a new question, it's works out just fine. You can also title a follow-up question with "follow-up", "take 2", "updated" or similar to make the distinction clear. Your new code certainly looks better, by the way. Can't really review it fully here in the comments, of course, but again feel free to post a new question, if you'd like (also just to get other opinions than mine)